# When I ping local IP address I get a reply from external IP

Tags: nat, sonicwall, dmz

I have SonicWall NSA 2400.
Port X2 is WAN port with following settings **X.X.X.250 / 255.255.255.248.**
I connected VPN concentrator to port X5, which is assigned to DMZ zone in Transporarent IP Mode for transparent range **X.X.X.252 / 255.255.255.255**.
VPN concentrator local ip is 192.168.1.65

I put a firewall rule  **WAN -> DMZ**  
 ANY X.X.X.252 HTTPS Allow.

The problem is that I can access HTTPS on the concentrator only for a few seconds after it restarts. While having a constant ping going to see if connect again with the LAN IP 192.168.1.65, then it gets NAT’ed to SonicWall Public IP X.X.X.250

```
Pinging 192.168.1.65 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.4: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.4: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.4: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.4: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time=677ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from X.X.X.250: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from X.X.X.250: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from X.X.X.250: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from X.X.X.250: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from X.X.X.250: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve managed to SSH to the VPN concentrator and able to edit routing table

```
X.X.X.248   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.254.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
0.0.0.0         X.X.X.249   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

so when I removed 192.168.1.1 as a gateway for 192.168.0.0/23

```
# route del -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
```

I started to get following reply

```
PING 192.168.1.65 -t
Pinging 192.168.1.65 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.65: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```